# How to block input send previously consulting to database

Tags: c#

I have a question as to how I can make an input that is making me submit to be blocked until a check is made on a previous page that I have?

In simple words I am saving a form that will be saved directly to the database and if the source is manual this is stored in the database with a char called 'S' the point is that if this is 'N' the button is blocked and if it is in 'S' the button is unlocked

how can I do this??

any ideas?

it's in MVC 2 C # with aspx

Comment: if you don't want to hit c# at all just validate it with javascript .

Comment: and how do I consult the Database, because first I have to validate that this record exists and, if it exists, it blocks the button

Answer (score 0):

It would help to include at least part of your code so other developers could help you better.

Anyway, as @Budyn has commented, you can use JavaScript / jQuery to disable/enable buttons.

Example, assuming your button has id="btnSubmit" and your controller is HomeController.

If the "N" or "S" value is coming from the database, you need to add an action in your controller that checks this value from your database and returns this value. You can then call this controller action in your script using ajax or jQuery [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). The following code is just an example to give you an idea.

In your controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...
    public JsonResult GetValue()
    {
        string result = null;

        // This is where you check database for the "N" or "S" value

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

In your script:

```
$.getJSON("/Home/GetValue", null, function (data) {
    if (data == "N") {
        $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else {
        $("#btnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```